Miller plateau voltage level in relation to gate resistor
I'm trying to simulate switch-on losses of a MOSFET, specifically IMT40R025M2H. From my understanding the gate voltage is mainly a function of gate charge Q_g, with a smaller influence from I_D and V_DD, and the rate of change of Q_g (meaning the value of gate current) should not be a factor.
Running the simulation with a 18V pulse with a resistor in series on the gate I get this graph. Red is the 18V pulse and yellow V_GS. It shows V_GS for values of gate resistance between 1 Ohm and 10 Ohm (top yellow line is 1 Ohm while bottom is 10 Ohm). I was expecting that as the resistance was increased the slope would be slower, but the voltage at which the plateau occurs would be the same, meaning the plateau would be reached later but at the same voltage level which is obviously not the case.
How exactly does the Miller plateau voltage level relate to the gate resistor, or better yet the gate current?


You should include a schematic. In particular, what load are you assuming?

The plateau voltage is highly dependent on a lot of different circuit characteristics; it's not really that useful as a figure of merit. Consider the physical origin of the plateau; it should be obvious that it depends on drain voltage, gate current, and load impedance at the very least.

I got an answer I was looking for on another forum, basically the voltage on my plot is the external gate-source voltage of the package, the internal gate-source voltage is pretty much consistent with what you'd expect. The external voltage differs because of parasitic components.
Link to the other post (with better explanation and graphs)
https://www.edaboard.com/threads/mosfet-datasheet-not-lining-up-with-spice-simulation.412732/#post-1782726


Miller plateau voltage level in relation to gate resistor

OK, you want to learn about the Miller plateau. Notice that the very first comment was Spehro 'speff' Pefhany asking about the circuit you are using, and especially about the load.

You should include a schematic. In particular, what load are you assuming?

Here's why.
I have created a circuit in CircuitLab (using a different MOSFET) that gives a simulation not too different from your own. Note that there is NO load on the drain in this circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Where is the Miller plateau in this circuit? Do you know?
Now here is a circuit that has a (variable) load. I am feeding a maximum of 1  amp into the drain of the MOSFET, but if the MOSFET is unable to handle that current, it flows into a Zener diode. In my simulation, the Zener voltage varies from 0 V to 60 V in 10 V increments. I keep the gate resistor a constant 10 \$\Omega\$.

simulate this circuit

As you can see from the simulation, the Miller plateau for this transistor in this circuit occurs when \$V_{GS}\approx 8\text{V}\$.
But note especially, that the width of the Miller plateau depends heavily on the maximum voltage at the drain (which in this circuit is controlled by the breakdown voltage of D1. When \$V_{DS}=0\$, and hence \$I_{D}=0\$ there is essentially no Miller plateau.

I was expecting that as the resistance was increased the slope would be slower, but the voltage at which the plateau occurs would be the same, meaning the plateau would be reached later but at the same voltage level which is obviously not the case.

Now, let's test that with a 60 V max \$V_{DS}\$ and a 1 A max \$I_D\$.

simulate this circuit

We see that the lower the gate resistor, the higher the apparent voltage for the Miller plateau. Why is this? Let's do some calculations. When the gate resistor is 2 \$\Omega\$, the Miller plateau voltage is about 13 V. That means there is an 18 - 13 = 5 V drop across the 2 \$\Omega\$ resistor, meaning there is 2.5 A flowing into the gate. When the gate resistor is 16 \$\Omega\$, there apparent Miller plateau voltage is about 7 V, so there is 18 - 7 = 11 V across the gate resistor. This implies a current of 11/16 or approximately 0.7 A. If there were an internal gate resistance of 3.5 \$\Omega\$, that would mean that when the external gate resistor is 2 \$\Omega\$, there will be an extra 2.5 x 3.5 = 8.75 V across the internal gate resistance, bringing the metalization voltage to about 13-8.75 = 4.25 V. When the external gate resistance is 16 \$\Omega\$, the current is about 0.7 A, and there would be about 0.7*3.5 = 2.5 V across the internal gate resistance, bringing the metalization voltage down to 7-2.5 = 4.5 V. I only eyeballed the voltages in the graph, so I am happy with this result. My guess is that the low current measurement of the Miller voltage would be between 4.25 and 4.5 V. Let's test this.

simulate this circuit

The plateau voltage is a little higher than I expected, but, again, I was doing very rough estimates from the graphs.
Finally, I would expect that when the gate voltage is about 4.5, the drain current would be about 1 A. That is, after all, our set-up. Let's test this.

simulate this circuit

Indeed, the gate voltage for which the drain current is 1 A is (for low drain voltages) between 4.6 and 4.65 V. All in all, I think the calculations fit
together fairly well.

Thank you for the extensive answer. I've tried replicating the second simulation you shared in Altium Designer, and I'm getting very different results. I'm new to the forum so I'm not sure how you add an image to a comment. This is the simulation I'm running, sweeping ZENER_VOLTAGE parameter between 0 and 60: https://ibb.co/Yk3R3F2And the results I'm getting https://ibb.co/VJpL13z

I see the first image link is wrong, this one should work
https://ibb.co/f00fVnF
